# Chromebook starts with magnified screen

Tags: resolution, chromebook, display-settings, google-chrome-os, hp-laptop

My son's HP Chromebook from school has 2 accounts. The one he's supposed to use goes to a massively magnified screen, the only time I see anything is when I move the cursor to the upper left corner of the screen, where the cursor fills half of it.

It's most likely some ready to restore setting, but what makes it hard is that I can't see if any Windows appear outside of the visible area on the screen.

The only thing I've tried is <-> to zoom out, but that does not work. I can zoom in a bit (!) with <+> and then back out, but not beyond the setting I started with.

Is there a way to restore the desktop to usable settings? Or maybe to go to a text login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these 2 things.

1. Go into settings>Device>Displays and make sure the Display size is set to the native size.
2. Go into settings>Advanced>Accessibility>Manage accessibility features>Display. Make sure fullscreen magnifier is disabled.